# How do I change the default ggplot2 colors from blue shades to orange shades?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have not found anything on the internet that even acknowledges that the default color of ggplot2 is blue, let alone providing instructions for changing it to other colors. Please help.

To be specific, I am working with geom_sf and trying to change the fill color gradient from a blue one to an orange one.

Comment: The default palette for mapping continuous values to a color or a fill is indeed on a range from medium blue to black. There are a variety of functions and packages to use a different palette. You might try `+ scale_fill_gradient(low = "black", high = "orange", aesthetics = "fill")`

Comment: Here's a package that specifically addresses your question: https://github.com/cararthompson/monochromeR